# onTouch giving weird touch points Android

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-imageview, ontouchlistener

Its quite simple thing which i am doing, i have done it before but now its not running as i expected. Anyways Let me explain briefly what i am trying to do and what i am getting::

**Scenario::**
I have a `RelativeLayout` in which an `ImageView` is placed, Now i set the `touchlistener` like this: `imageview.setOnTouchListener(this);`

It asked me to override the `onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event)` function which i did...
and in the `Action_Move` i get the **x** and **y** and add them to left and top margins, in this way I am moving my image.

**Weird Problem:**
My `ImageView` is moving but with a very noticeable shake, like if i am moving in right direction, `ImageView` will go to right side but on its way it comes back to left side so that it looks like image is not stable, its vibrating.. something like that.. I am giving the **x** and **y** which i get during `log`... hope this gives you the idea.

```
ACTION_DOWN[#0(pid 0)=160,233]  Going right..
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=160,233]  ////
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=160,233]  //
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=174,231]  //
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=176,233]  //
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=196,232]  //
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=152,232]  // suddenly i got 152 as location for x... image comes     back
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=167,232]  // again started to go right
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=180,233]  // going right
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=173,233]  // again comes a little back
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=187,232]  // same thing goes till end..
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=159,232]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=174,231]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=177,233]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=189,231]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=155,232]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=171,231]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=183,230]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=161,234]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=171,233]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=174,230]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=183,230]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=162,234]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=170,233]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=176,233]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=165,233]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=175,232]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=163,233]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=171,233]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=167,233]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=172,232]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=178,232]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=158,234]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=170,234]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=170,232]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=177,231]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=157,234]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=160,234]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=169,232]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=165,233]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=167,233]
ACTION_MOVE[#0(pid 0)=159,233]
ACTION_UP  [#0(pid 0)=161,233]
```

XML code for RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#99000000">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:scaleType="matrix" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So, this is the max, i could explain my question, still if you need anything, let me know.

**Update::**
Code for moving the `ImageView` in its Container i.e `RelativeLayout`:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) imageview.getLayoutParams();

            params.leftMargin = params.leftMargin + x;
            params.topMargin = params.topMargin + y;

            imageview.setLayoutParams(params);
            break;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The X and Y variables in `onTouch` are the X and Y relative to the View which has the `onTouchListener` attached. so 10, 10 would be from the top left of your `ImageView` not of the `RelativeLayout`.

If you use these values to move your `ImageView` then you will naturally get shaky behavior, each move action will also fire a slightly different OnTouchEvent causing another move action - this recursion gives you a "vibrating" effect.

Comment: "each move action will also fire a slightly different OnTouchEvent causing another move action - this recursion gives you a "vibrating" effect." Please explain it a little, a link/documentation would be very helpful where it has been written in detail...

Answer (score 0):

When I obtained the Y coordination by the method `event.getRawY()` instead of `event.getY()` to move a View ,the shaky behavior disappear.
So if you had used the `getY()` method , try to change it.