# Android custom horizontal drag tremble

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, slide

I created a class that should be used to allow user to horizontally relocate a view by sliding his finger on a bar, the code is this

```
public class Dragger implements View.OnTouchListener {
  private View toDrag;
  private Point startDragPoint;
  private int offset;
  public Dragger (View bar, View toDragg){
    toDrag = toDragg;
    dragging = false;
    bar.setOnTouchListener(this);
  }
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent evt) {
    switch (evt.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          startDragPoint = new Point((int) evt.getX(), (int) evt.getY());
          offset = startDragPoint.x - (int) toDrag.getX();
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          int currentX = (int)evt.getX();
          Log.d("LOG","currentX=" + currentX);
          toDrag.setX(currentX-offset);
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            int difference = (startDragPoint.x-offset)-(int)toDrag.getX();
            if(difference<-125){
              ((ViewManager) toDrag.getParent()).removeView(toDrag);
            }else{
                toDrag.setX(startDragPoint.x-offset);
            }
            dragging = false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

In the oncreate of the main activity i just use it by calling his constructor like this:

```
new Dragger(barItem,itemToDrag);
```

It apparently work, but it seems to tremble a lot while dragging... I tried to understand why does it work so strangely, so i added a Log instruction in the ACTION_MOVE, and the result is that... even if i only move to right pixel by pixel sometimes the currentX instead of increasing by 1 it decrease of a variable number, sometimes 10, sometimes 18 and when i go to the next pixel it turn back to normal by increasing of 1...
That really doesen't make sense...
Some ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First guess:** There are other fingers on the device which causes move to work erratically

**Second guess:** Right now you seem to be using the `setX` method more like a `moveX` and specifying the increment by which the function moves. This might not be what it was designed for

**Third Point:**
Sometimes the move function acts finicky. It is always run (as in whenever there is a pointer on the screen) and depends on the position of the finger. I would recommend changing the function to make it like a step

**Suggestion** 
Make the action move like a step function that takes one value

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
      int currentX = (int)evt.getX();
      if(abs(currentX)>10)currentX=(int) currentX/5;
      toDrag.setX(currentX-offset);
```

Comment: First: There areno other finger, at the beginning i supposed it may be a problem like that, so for trying the increment pixel by pixel i used teamviewer quicksupport and setted the mouse sensibility at the minimum.
Second: the real problem is not in the setX, even if stop dragging the item and let it stand the currentX value still keep acting strange
Suggestion: Basically you are saying me that i should approximate the position? Maybe it work, but that would made the drag not fluent

Comment: I read the answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574985/ontouch-giving-weird-touch-points-android and i'm starting to think that when i use setX that fire another ACTION_MOVE event

Comment: Wait the bar is contained within the draggable view? That will give you shaky co-ordinates because the you are reporting XY on the bar and trying to move the bar at the same time.

Comment: Yes it is, anyway i solved by taking the bar out of the toDrag view, so i accept your answer since you are the only one that tried to help me :D